# node.send inside RED.httpAdmin.post not working after re-deploy

Tags: node-red

I'm sending `items` array by using `$.post` from frontend to backend. In backend I'm hitting `RED.httpAdmin.post` route and I can see payload successfully reach backend. I also want to send this `items` array to the next node by using `node.send` method inside `RED.httpAdmin.post` but when I re-deploy app, `node.send` is stopped working. How can I solve this issue, here is the current code.

HTML:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  RED.nodes.registerType("Opcua Browser", {
    category: "Opcua",
    color: "#00cccc",
    defaults: {
      endpoint: { value: "", required: true, type: "OpcUa-Endpoint" },
      topic: { value: "" },
      plcName: { value: "" },
      items: { value: [] },
      checkedItems: { value: [] },
    },
    inputs: 0,
    outputs: 1,
    align: "left",
    icon: "font-awesome/fa-search",
    label: "Opcua Browser",
    oneditprepare: function () {
      const generateOption = (data) => {
        var container = $("<li/>", {
          style:
            "padding: 5px 0;display:flex;gap:10px;align-items:center;border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;",
        });
        var rowInclude = $("<input/>", {
          type: "checkbox",
          style: "width:20%;text-align:center; float:left;",
          class: "node-input-option-include",
          checked: data.include || this.checkedItems.includes(data.nodeId),
        }).appendTo(container);
        var rowName = $("<input/>", {
          style: "width: 25%;text-align:center; float:left;",
          type: "text",
          value: data.displayName.text,
          class: "node-input-option-name",
        }).appendTo(container);
        var rowNodeId = $("<div/>", {
          style:
            "width: 35%;text-align:center; float:left;white-space: nowrap;overflow: hidden;text-overflow: ellipsis;",
          text: data.nodeId,
          class: "node-input-option-nodeId",
        }).appendTo(container);
        var rowType = $("<div/>", {
          style:
            "width: 20%;text-align:center; float:left;white-space: nowrap;overflow: hidden;text-overflow: ellipsis;",
          text: data.dataValue.value.dataType,
          class: "node-input-option-type",
        }).appendTo(container);
        $("#node-input-option-container").append(container);
      };
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
      });
      const fetch = () => {
        $.getJSON("plc-options/" + this.id, function (data) {
          if (data.length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
              generateOption(data[i]);
            }
            $("#loading").empty();
          } else {
            $("#loading").text("Loading...");
            $("#node-input-option-container").empty();
            setTimeout(fetch, 1000);
          }
        }).fail((jqxhr, textStatus, error) => {
          if (error === "Not Found") {
            $("#loading").text("Fill necessary areas and press deploy.");
          }
        });
      };
      $.getJSON("plc-options/checked-items/" + this.id, (data) => {
        this.checkedItems = data;
      }).always(() => {
        if (this.items.length === 0) {
          fetch();
        } else {
          for (var i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++) {
            generateOption(this.items[i]);
          }
        }
      });
      $("#refresh").click(() => {
        $.getJSON("plc-options/refresh/" + this.id).then(() => {
          fetch();
        });
      });
    },
    oneditsave: function () {
      const items = $("#node-input-option-container").children();
      const plcName = $("#node-input-plcName").val();
      var node = this;
      node.plcName = plcName;
      node.items = [];
      items.each(function (i) {
        var option = $(this);
        var o = {
          include: option.find(".node-input-option-include").is(":checked"), //typedInput('value'),
          displayName: { text: option.find(".node-input-option-name").val() }, //typedInput('value'),
          nodeId: option.find(".node-input-option-nodeId").text(), //typedInput('value')
          dataValue: {
            value: { dataType: option.find(".node-input-option-type").text() },
          },
        };
        node.items.push(o);
      });
      const includedItems = node.items.filter((item) => item.include);
      this.checkedItems = includedItems;
      $.post("plc-options/update/structure/" + this.id, {
        items: includedItems.length === 0 ? ["empty"] : includedItems, //jquery not allowing me to send [] array
        plcName,
      });
    },
  });
</script>

<script type="text/x-red" data-template-name="Opcua Browser">
      <div class="form-row" style="min-width:640px">
          <label for="node-input-endpoint"><i class="icon-bookmark"></i> Endpoint</label>
          <input type="text" id="node-input-endpoint">
      </div>
      <div class="form-row">
          <label for="node-input-topic"><i class="icon-search"></i> Topic</label>
          <input type="text" id="node-input-topic" placeholder="ns=0;i=85">
      </div>
      <div class="form-row">
          <label for="node-input-plcName"><i class="icon-search"></i>PLC Name</label>
          <input type="text" id="node-input-plcName" placeholder="PLC_1">
      </div>
      <div class="form-row node-input-option-container-row" style="margin-bottom:0px; width:100%; min-width:520px">
        <label style="display:block;white-space: nowrap;"><i class="fa fa-list-alt"></i> <span data-i18n="">OPCUA Items</label>
        <div style="display:inline-block; width:100%; border:1px solid #ccc; border-radius:5px; box-sizing:border-box;">
          <div class="red-ui-tray-header" style="width:100%; display: inline-block; padding:10px 0; border-top:0px solid; border-radius:5px 5px 0 0; border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;">
              <div style="width:calc(100% - 15px); display:flex;gap:10px;align-items:center;">
                <div style="width:20%;text-align:center;" data-i18n="Name">Include</span></div>
                <div style="width:25%;text-align:center;" data-i18n="Name">Name</span></div>
                <div style="width:35%;text-align:center;" data-i18n="NodeId">NodeId</div>
                <div style="width:20%;text-align:center;" data-i18n="Type">Type</div>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div id="node-input-option-container-div" style="height: 257px;overflow-y:scroll;position:relative;">
            <div id='loading' style='position: absolute;left:50%;transform:translateX(-50%);top:115px;font-size: 18px;'></div>
            <ol id="node-input-option-container" style="list-style-type:none; margin: 0;"></ol>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div style="display:flex;align-items:center;" class="form-row">
        <button id="refresh"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i> Refresh</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</script>
```

JS:

```js
module.exports = function (RED) {
    "use strict";
    var opcua = require('node-opcua');
    var uaclient = require('node-opcua-client');
    const NodeCrawler = require("node-opcua-client-crawler").NodeCrawler;
    const structureSocketInstance = require('./structureSocket.js');
    const axios = require("axios");
    const { v4: uuidv4 } = require("uuid");

    function OpcUaBrowserNode(config) {
        RED.nodes.createNode(this, config);
        this.topic = config.topic || "ns=0;i=85";
        this.plcName = config.plcName;
        this.isRefresh = config.isRefresh;
        this.items = config.items;
        this.checkedItems = config.checkedItems;
        var node = this;
        node.context().set('loading', true);
        node.context().set('checkedItems', []);

        var opcuaEndpoint = RED.nodes.getNode(config.endpoint);

        var connectionOption = {};
        var userIdentity = {};

        if (opcuaEndpoint.securityPolicy) {
            connectionOption.securityPolicy = opcua.SecurityPolicy[opcuaEndpoint.securityPolicy];
        }
        else {
            connectionOption.securityPolicy = opcua.SecurityPolicy.None;
        }
        if (opcuaEndpoint.securityMode) {
            connectionOption.securityMode = opcua.MessageSecurityMode[opcuaEndpoint.securityMode];
        }
        else {
            connectionOption.securityPolicy = opcua.MessageSecurityMode.None;
        }
        connectionOption.endpointMustExist = false;

        if (opcuaEndpoint.login) {
            userIdentity.userName = opcuaEndpoint.credentials.user;
            userIdentity.password = opcuaEndpoint.credentials.password;
            userIdentity.type = uaclient.UserTokenType.UserName; // New TypeScript API parameter
        }

        const startSearching = () => {
            if (this.plcName === '') {
                node.status({
                    fill: "red",
                    shape: "dot",
                    text: "Please fill plc name area.",
                });
            } else {
                setupClient(opcuaEndpoint.endpoint);
            }
        }

        setTimeout(() => {
            if (this.checkedItems.length > 0) {
                node.send({
                    payload: this.checkedItems.map((item) => ({
                        name: item.displayName.text,
                        topic: item.nodeId,
                        datatype: item.dataValue.value.dataType,
                    }))
                }, false);
            }
        }, 500);

        if (node.items.length === 0) {
            startSearching();
        } else {
            node.status({
                fill: "green",
                shape: "dot",
                text: "Successfully found all variables.",
            });
        }

        async function setupClient(url) {
            try {
                const client = opcua.OPCUAClient.create(connectionOption);
                const items = [];
                await client.connect(url);
                const session = await client.createSession(userIdentity);
                var crawler = new NodeCrawler(session);
                node.status({
                    fill: "blue",
                    shape: "dot",
                    text: "Browsing variables in the server.",
                });
                crawler.on("browsed", function (element) {
                    // 2 means variable type
                    if (element.nodeClass === 2 && element.accessLevel === 3) {
                        items.push(element);
                    }
                });
                await crawler.read(node.topic);
                node.context().set(`${node.id}-plc-options`, [...items]);
                node.context().set(`loading`, false);
                node.status({
                    fill: "green",
                    shape: "dot",
                    text: "Successfully found all variables.",
                });
                client.disconnect();
            }
            catch (err) {
                node.status({
                    fill: "red",
                    shape: "dot",
                    text: err,
                });
            }
        }

        const checkedItemListControl = setInterval(() => {
            if (node.context().get('checkListChanged')) {
                node.send({
                    payload: node.context().get('checkedItems').map((item) => ({
                        name: item.displayName.text,
                        topic: item.nodeId,
                        datatype: item.dataValue.value.dataType,
                    }))
                }, false);
                node.context().set('checkListChanged', false);
            }
        }, 1500);

        RED.httpAdmin.get("/plc-options/" + node.id, function (req, res) {
            if (node.context().get('loading')) {
                res.json([]);
            } else {
                res.json(node.context().get(`${node.id}-plc-options`));
            }
        });

        RED.httpAdmin.get("/plc-options/refresh/" + node.id, function (req, res) {
            node.context().set(`loading`, true);
            startSearching();
            res.json("loading");
        });

        RED.httpAdmin.get("/plc-options/checked-items/" + node.id, async function (req, res) {
            const { data } = await axios("http://localhost:8000/api/v1/structure/node-red");
            const structure = JSON.parse(data.nodeRed.replaceAll("'", '"').replaceAll('`', "'"));
            const plcIndex = structure.findIndex(item => item.id === node.id);
            if (plcIndex === -1)
                res.json([]);
            else {
                const childsNodeIds = structure[plcIndex].childs.map((childId) => structure.find((item) => item.id === childId).nodeId);
                res.json(childsNodeIds);
            }
        });

        RED.httpAdmin.post("/plc-options/update/structure/" + node.id, async function (req, res) {
            const { data } = await axios("http://localhost:8000/api/v1/structure/node-red");
            const structure = JSON.parse(data.nodeRed.replaceAll("'", '"').replaceAll('`', "'"));
            const plcIndex = structure.findIndex(item => item.id === node.id);
            const childs = req.body.items.filter((item) => item !== "empty").map((item) => ({
                id: uuidv4(),
                name: item.displayName.text,
                topic: item.nodeId,
                datatype: item.dataValue.value.dataType,
                value: `${req.body.plcName}-${item.displayName.text}`,
                plcName: req.body.plcName,
                childs: [],
                parentId: node.id,
                isOpen: false,
                isShown: plcIndex !== -1 ? structure[plcIndex].isOpen : false,
                type: 10,
            }));
            const parentPlc = {
                id: node.id,
                childs: childs.map((child) => child.id),
                parentId: "2",
                isOpen: plcIndex !== -1 ? structure[plcIndex].isOpen : false,
                isShown: plcIndex !== -1 ? structure[plcIndex].isShown : false,
                name: req.body.plcName,
                type: 9,
            }
            if (!structure[0].childs.includes(node.id)) {
                structure[0].childs.push(node.id)
            }
            if (plcIndex !== -1) {
                let currentIndex = plcIndex + 1;
                //removing childs
                while (structure[currentIndex] && structure[currentIndex].parentId !== '2') {
                    structure.splice(currentIndex, 1);
                    ++currentIndex;
                }
                structure[plcIndex] = parentPlc;
                childs.forEach((child, i) => {
                    structure.splice(plcIndex + i + 1, 0, child);
                })
            } else {
                structure.push(parentPlc);
                childs.forEach(child => {
                    structure.push(child);
                });
            }
            const escapeSingQuote = JSON.stringify(structure).replaceAll("'", '`')
            await axios({
                method: "put",
                url: `http://localhost:8000/api/v1/structure/node-red`,
                data: {
                    nodeRed: escapeSingQuote.replaceAll('"', "'"),
                },
            });
            structureSocketInstance.emit("refetch", () => {
                return "true";
            });
            node.context().set('checkListChanged', true);
            node.context().set('checkedItems', req.body.items.filter((item) => item !== "empty"));
            res.json("success");
        });

        node.on("close", async (removed, done) => {
            clearInterval(checkedItemListControl);
            if (removed) {
                const { data } = await axios("http://localhost:8000/api/v1/structure/node-red");
                const structure = JSON.parse(data.nodeRed.replaceAll("'", '"').replaceAll('`', "'"));
                const plcIndex = structure.findIndex(item => item.id === node.id);
                if (plcIndex !== -1) {
                    structure[0].childs = structure[0].childs.filter((childId) => childId !== node.id)
                    let currentIndex = plcIndex + 1;
                    while (structure[currentIndex] && structure[currentIndex].parentId !== '2') {
                        structure.splice(currentIndex, 1);
                        ++currentIndex;
                    }
                    structure.splice(plcIndex, 1);
                    const escapeSingQuote = JSON.stringify(structure).replaceAll("'", '`')
                    await axios({
                        method: "put",
                        url: `http://localhost:8000/api/v1/structure/node-red`,
                        data: {
                            nodeRed: escapeSingQuote.replaceAll('"', "'"),
                        },
                    });
                    structureSocketInstance.emit("refetch", () => {
                        return "true";
                    });
                    done();
                }
            } else {
                done();
            }
        })
    }
    RED.nodes.registerType("Opcua Browser", OpcUaBrowserNode);
}
```

StructureSocket

```js
const socketio = require("socket.io");

const SOCKET_PORT = 3000;

const structureSocketInstance = socketio(SOCKET_PORT, {
    cors: {
        origin: "*",
        methods: ["GET", "POST"],
        credentials: true,
        transports: ["websocket", "polling"],
    },
});

module.exports = structureSocketInstance;
```

Comment: Show a LOT more context for the backend code. But this probably not going to work (e.g. on first deploy when the node doesn't actually exist at time of editing)

Comment: I also suspect you are leaking express routes and never cleaning up

Comment: I added the whole html, and js files I use just to be clear. My main purpose in this node is to browse all nodes in plc and show them on table. Using setInterval solved node.send issue but I think it is not a good solution. Also I believe your suspicion is true, I didn't know I need to clean them. Well to be honest I do not think my node is in good shape. I used node.context to show loading in table which also not be optimal. And I wonder importing socket connection like I did is ok?